# How can I output UIAlertController to a separate file and output data from there?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uialertcontroller, completion

I'm trying to output alert to a separate function, since there will be many similar ones.

Here is my alert:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func alertEditSum(nameCell: String, completion: (() -> Void)) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default , handler: { _ in
            let nameFolderField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
            if nameFolderField.isTextFieldCheck(text: nameFolderField.text!) == true {
                
                // -----here----
                
            }
        }))
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel"
                                                
                                                , style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (nameField: UITextField!) -> Void in
            nameField.clearButtonMode = .always
            nameField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
            
        })
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

and my piece of code is in another VC:

```
self.sortedDate[indexPath.section-1].personPayment = Double(nameFolderField.text!)!
 do {
try! self.context.save()
collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is that I need to consider what exactly the user enters in UITextField. text! (nameFolderField.text!). I also can't add completion to the alert code, writes an error.

Completion should be added to the line where it says: / / - - - - - here----

Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: And what was the error exactly? Also, what's the method `isTextFieldCheck(text:)`? It's an extension on `UITextField`, but shouldn't it check its own text field (so no need to give the text parameter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
func alertEditSum(nameCell: String, completion: @escaping ((String?) -> Void)) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        let nameFolderField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        if nameFolderField.isTextFieldCheck(text: nameFolderField.text!) == true {
            completion(nameFolderField.text)
        }
    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
        completion(nil)
    }))

    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: { nameField in
        nameField.clearButtonMode = .always
        nameField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    })

    self.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

To call it:

```
theViewController.alertEditSum(nameCell: "text") { text in
    if let text = text {
        //Do stuff
    } else { //Text is invalid or user has cancel

    }
}
```

Now, `isTextFieldCheck(text:)` is I guess a method on `UITextField`, since it's checking its own text, why giving it as a parameter?
Why not just `func isTextValid()`?

I would also avoid the force unwrap: `!`.

Going further, would be to use `Result<String, Error>` in the completion:
`completion((Result<String, Error>) -> Void))` to have more infos if needed (user has canceled, text wasn't not valid for any reason, etc.)

Comment: If you mean it  func isTextValid() by this nameFolderField.isTextFieldCheck(text: nameFolderField.text! There I have a check not only for letters, but also many other things. Your answer helped a lot! Just a little bit was not enough to solve it!)

Comment: No, I meant that it could be `func isTextValid() -> Bool { guard let text = self.text else { return false } //do the rest of the check with text }`

Answer (score 1):

You neeed **@escaping** completion to send value from inside a closure to a caller , Main changes **completion:@escaping (String?) -> Void)** and **completion(nameFolderField.text)**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func alertEditSum(nameCell: String,completion:@escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default , handler: { _ in
            let nameFolderField = alertController.textFields!.first!
            if nameFolderField.isTextFieldCheck(text: nameFolderField.text!) {
              completion(nameFolderField.text)
            } 
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (nameField: UITextField!) -> Void in
            nameField.clearButtonMode = .always
            nameField.keyboardType = .decimalPad 
        })
        self.present(alertController, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

Call

```
alertEditSum(nameCell:<#SomeValue#>) { result in
  print(result)
}
```